# How to change the IP Address of http request?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have TWO applications hosted on individual physical servers.

1. Authentication Application - ServerA - can be accessed from anywhere
2. Some Business Application - ServerB - must be accessed by ServerA application only

The access rule: "Server-B can only accept the request from Server-A's IP Address".

User first goes to the Authentication application(aspx page) and provides his credentials. On successful login, I am redirecting the user to Server-B. While redirection, end user's ip address remains persistent, and Server-B interprets that the request is raised from somewhere else.

There is a solution using proxy server. I can install the proxy server on Server-A and redirect the request through (WebProxy object) it so the IP will remain same for all requests to Server-B.

But just wanted to know... Is there any way to do it without proxy? Is there any chances to achieve through request IP address spoofing? or something else which I didn't think about??

Comment: If you spoof the IP address, then Server B will send it's *response* back to Server A - which is not listening for a response.

Comment: Not able to understand, can you little elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your access rule to this: "Server-B can only accept requests that were referred by Server-A's IP address"

Then you could check the URL Referrer on the first request after authentication and then allow the user's IP address from that point forward.

Otherwise, a proxy is the only way to enforce your original rule that I know of.

Comment: But referrer spoofing is *trivial* to accomplish so server B may as well be configured to be open to the world.